# How to pre select Page or Post Parent (ID) from Dropdown automatically?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
function autoset_parent_dropdown() {
    global $pagenow;
    if($pagenow == 'post-new.php') {
        parent_dropdown( '477', '477', '0', null );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'autoset_parent_dropdown' );
```

How to pre select Page or Post Parent (ID) from Dropdown automatically?

**on post-new.php, When creating new post.**

I am trying above code but its not working. Its not selecting any parent post/page using parent_dropdown function.

I referred: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/parent_dropdown/

Please correct me if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is the drop down not being populated? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Corrected. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. Tested on Wordpress 5.3.2, but should work on all versions.

```
add_filter('default_content', 'assign_parent_to_new_post', 10, 2);
/**
 * @param string $post_content
 * @param WP_Post $post
 *
 * @return string
 */
function assign_parent_to_new_post($post_content, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type != 'page') {
        return $post_content;
    }

    $post->post_parent = 7; //Parent post_id goes here
    wp_update_post($post);
    return $post_content;
}
```

The idea behind it is pretty simple – hook somewhere inside blank post creation process, substitute post_parent and then push it to the database.

Comment: Its not working sir. I just tried this. I am catching post parent id using url param: parent_id=7, But its not working.

Comment: could you tell me how to use:  parent_dropdown function (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/parent_dropdown/) for this???

Comment: Try please 477 instead of 7

Comment: I used 477, I just told 7 for your example sir. Please help :(

Comment: What is your version of wordpress?

Comment: Where you have located this code?
p.s: It works for me in 5.4 with Classic Editor. Code is in functions.php file of a theme.

Important notice: It will work ONLY for new 'pages' (post-new.php?post_type=page)

Comment: Actually I am using post hierarchy. I want to use this for post type: post. not page. Do I have to change anything in the code?

Comment: `$post->post_type != 'post'`

Comment: OK I will try & I will let you know about if it works or not. Thanks for having in connection of me since last few days :)

Comment: I change the code according to what you provided above. But its not working :(